# Terrain option for custom gmap style?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

It says google maps API was recently updated to enable terrain for custom maps. I want to use my custom style and add the terrain. I do not get the option to add terrain to my custom map and I'd like to do that by default. Can you please advice?

```
 style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU  ,
       mapTypeIds: ['Dark',google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
    }
  };
```

Here's a [link to my map](http://www.montao.com.br).

Thanks

[image]

Update: I tried with a relief map that can look like this but I also want yellow borders, red dots for citis and dark water since this is not s styled map it's a relief map
[image]

The original static non-gmap map photo I want to resemble is

[image]

Comment: Where does it say the API was updated to enable terrain for custom maps?  I'm looking through the change log at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog and I don't see it.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2507 now says "fixed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the styling wizard:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

You should be able to make the water black, and to change the appearance of country borders and labels, but you cannot re-style the base relief imagery.